# Hello I do NOT understand these 'not defined' errors and 'no while

Tags: c#

So, I am a noob to coding in C# *but* I have used unity, which uses C#. Well get all these errors:

```
Compilation error (line 8, col 6): } expected
Compilation error (line 13, col 33): Empty character literal
Compilation error (line 21, col 9): Invalid token 'while' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 21, col 16): Type expected
Compilation error (line 21, col 16): Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Compilation error (line 21, col 16): ) expected
Compilation error (line 21, col 16): Invalid token 'true' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 23, col 17): Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 23, col 17): Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 23, col 29): Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 23, col 30): Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Compilation error (line 23, col 31): Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 25, col 23): Type expected
Compilation error (line 25, col 23): Syntax error, ',' expected
Compilation error (line 26, col 22): Syntax error, '>' expected
Compilation error (line 26, col 22): Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Compilation error (line 26, col 22): ) expected
Compilation error (line 26, col 22): Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 27, col 16): Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 27, col 16): Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 27, col 23): Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Compilation error (line 28, col 26): Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 28, col 29): Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Compilation error (line 28, col 30): Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 29, col 20): Tuple must contain at least two elements.
Compilation error (line 29, col 20): ) expected
Compilation error (line 29, col 20): Invalid token '!=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 31, col 20): Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 31, col 20): Invalid token '=' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
Compilation error (line 31, col 32): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 31, col 36): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 35, col 1): Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.
Compilation error (line 34, col 14): 'else' cannot start a statement.
Compilation error (line 34, col 14): Syntax error, '(' expected
Compilation error (line 34, col 14): Invalid expression term 'else'
Compilation error (line 34, col 14): ) expected
Compilation error (line 34, col 14): Invalid expression term 'else'
Compilation error (line 34, col 14): ; expected
Compilation error (line 67, col 9): Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Compilation error (line 69, col 5): Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Compilation error (line 70, col 1): Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Compilation error (line 31, col 22): Method must have a return type
Compilation error (line 31, col 22): 'Demo.Demo(all, ch)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
Compilation error (line 31, col 29): The type or namespace name 'all' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Compilation error (line 31, col 34): The type or namespace name 'ch' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Compilation error (line 27, col 24): The type 'Demo' already contains a definition for 'val'
Compilation error (line 7, col 17): The entry point of the program is global code; ignoring 'Demo.Main()' entry point.
Compilation error (line 37, col 17): The name 'cmd' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 37, col 23): The name 'all' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 38, col 17): The name 'all' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 39, col 17): The name 'all' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 39, col 23): The name 'Concat' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 39, col 30): The name 'all' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 39, col 35): The name 'ch' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 42, col 17): The name 'ch' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 44, col 21): The name 'cmd' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 46, col 38): The name 'path2' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 48, col 67): The name 'path2' does not exist in the current context
Compilation error (line 19, col 14): The field 'Demo.ch' is never used
Compilation error (line 27, col 24): The field 'Demo.val' is never used
Compilation error (line 14, col 24): The field 'Demo.all' is assigned but its value is never used
Compilation error (line 15, col 24): The field 'Demo.cmd' is assigned but its value is never used
Compilation error (line 18, col 13): The field 'Demo.val' is assigned but its value is never used
```

And here is my source code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        public string path = @"SCRIPT.vis";
        public string path2 = @"header.asm";


        private char previous = '';
        private string all = "";
        private string cmd = "";
        
        Stream s = new FileStream(@"data.vi", FileMode.Open);
        int val = 0;
        char ch;

        while (true)
        {
            val = s.ReadByte();

            if (val < 0)
                break;
            ch = (char)val;
            Console.Write(ch);
            if (ch != "(")
            {
               all = Concat(all, ch);
               
               
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = all;
                all = "";
                all = Concat(all, ch);
                
            }
            if (ch == ")")
            {
                if (cmd == "os.Start")
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(path2))
                    {
                         using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path2))
                         {
                             sw.WriteLine("section .multiboot_header");
                             sw.WriteLine("header_start:");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dd 0xe85250d6");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dd 0");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dd header_end - header_start");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dd 0x100000000 - (0xe85250d6 + 0 + (header_end - header_start))");
                             sw.WriteLine("     ");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dw 0");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dw 0");
                             sw.WriteLine("     dd 8");
                             sw.WriteLine("header_end:");


                         }    
                    }    
                }    
            }    
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

So, thanks for the help!
BTW this is for a compiler for stuff. Also, *if for some reason you need this* I am running (well testing for errors) my code on an online compiler, DOTNETFIDDLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
    public string path = @"SCRIPT.vis";
    public string path2 = @"header.asm";


    private char previous = '';
    private string all = "";
    private string cmd = "";
```

should be

```
    string path = @"SCRIPT.vis";
    string path2 = @"header.asm";


    char previous = '';
    string all = "";
    string cmd = "";
```

also since ch is a char this

```
    if (ch != "(")
```

should be

```
    if (ch != '(')
```

Comment: Also, `private char previous = ''` is an _Empty character literal_. You can have empty strings (i.e. a string of length 0), but there's no such thing as an empty character. You need _exactly_ one character between the single quotes

Comment: @Flydog57 i was going to add a caveat saying i had not compiled the code, just read it so i might have missed some things, seems like i did miss that

Comment: Always compile....